# Update same column on multiple rows with different values

Tags: php, sql, multiple-columns

I want to run a `cron job` daily to update the `dadmin_reminder_date`, `dshipment_date`, and `darrival_date`. I need to add `icmd_days` to each of the current dates.

Ex. For the second row(couldn't upload the image) the 
output should be 
`old(05/07/2015)/new(06/04/2015),old(05/07/2015)/new(06/04/2015),old(05/15/2015)new(06/12/2015)`. The `icmd_days = 28` for this row. Each row has a different amount of days or `icmd_days` value.

Here is the `php` code that I have so far, however it is updating each row with the same amount of days.

```
require '../commonincludefiles.php';

global $conn;

$row_string = '';

$Today = date("Y-m-d");

global $conn;



$sub_query = "SELECT bisubscriptionID,dshipment_date,darrival_date,icmd_days,dadmin_reminder_date,vsubscriptionstatus FROM tbl_subscription WHERE darrival_date <= '".$Today."' AND edelete='0' AND vsubscriptionstatus='Shipped'";
$sub_res = mysqli_query($conn,$sub_query);
    $temp = array();
    if (mysqli_num_rows($sub_res) >0) {
    $i=0;
    while($row =  mysqli_fetch_array($sub_res)){
        $temp[$i]['bisubscriptionID'] = $row['bisubscriptionID'];
        $temp[$i]['icmd_days'] = $row['icmd_days'];
        $temp[$i]['new_dshipment_date'] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($row['dshipment_date'] . '+ '.$row['icmd_days'].'days'));
        $i++;



$new_vsubscriptionstatus = 'Active';


$update_query = "UPDATE tbl_subscription SET vsubscriptionstatus='" . $new_vsubscriptionstatus . "',dshipment_date='" . $new_dshipment_date . "',tmodifydate=NOW() WHERE darrival_date <= '".$Today."' AND edelete='0' AND vsubscriptionstatus='Shipped' AND bisubscriptionID= $bisubscriptionID";
$update_res = mysqli_query($conn, $update_query);
}
}
?>
```

Please go easy on me. I have never coded before and was handed a website to have fun with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you can change your update statement to look like this and remove your select all together:

```
UPDATE tbl_subscription 
SET vsubscriptionstatus = '" . $new_vsubscriptionstatus . "'
    ,dshipment_date=DATEADD(d,icmd_days,shipment_date)
    ,tmodifydate=NOW() 
WHERE darrival_date <= '".$Today."' 
AND edelete='0' 
AND vsubscriptionstatus='Shipped' 
AND bisubscriptionID= $bisubscriptionID
```

Date add automatically adds the number of days in ICMD_DAYS to the shipment_date and sets your date accordingly.

Also you can remove your today logic for the built in GETDATE() function in SQL:

```
UPDATE tbl_subscription 
SET vsubscriptionstatus = '" . $new_vsubscriptionstatus . "'
    ,dshipment_date=DATEADD(d,icmd_days,shipment_date)
    ,tmodifydate=NOW() 
WHERE darrival_date <= GETDATE()
AND edelete='0' 
AND vsubscriptionstatus='Shipped' 
AND bisubscriptionID= $bisubscriptionID
```

I am guessing you are using MySQL not SQL Server. Here is how to do this in MySQL. I also wrote out example code for a schema I created on my server called stackoverflow.

I included the drop table in case you want to re-run the code after any tweaks.

```
USE stackoverflow;

DROP TABLE `tbl_subscription`;

CREATE TABLE `tbl_subscription` (
  `dshipment_date` DATE NULL,
  `icmd_days` INT NULL,
  `darrival_date` DATETIME NULL,
  `edelete` BIT NULL,
  `csubscriptionstatus` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `bisubscriptionID` BIGINT NULL,
  `dadmin_reminder_date` DATE NULL,
  `dprevious_shipment_date` DATE NULL,
  `tmodifydate` DATETIME NULL
  )
ENGINE = InnoDB;


INSERT INTO `tbl_subscription`
    (
    dshipment_date
    ,icmd_days
    ,darrival_date
    ,edelete
    ,csubscriptionstatus
    ,bisubscriptionID
    ,dadmin_reminder_date
    ,tmodifydate
    )

SELECT 
    '2015-04-30' as dshipment_date
    ,30 as icmd_days
    ,null as darrival_date
    ,0 as edelete
    ,'Shipped' as csubscriptionstatus
    ,20150001 as bisubscriptionID
    ,null as dadmin_reminder_date
    ,NOW() as tmodifydate 
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    '2015-05-10' as dshipment_date
    ,25 as icmd_days
    ,null as darrival_date
    ,0 as edelete
    ,'Shipped' as csubscriptionstatus
    ,20150002 as bisubscriptionID
    ,null as dadmin_reminder_date
    ,NOW() as tmodifydate 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 
    '2015-04-10' as dshipment_date
    ,30 as icmd_days
    ,'2015-04-13' as darrival_date
    ,0 as edelete
    ,'Shipped' as csubscriptionstatus
    ,20150003 as bisubscriptionID
    ,null as dadmin_reminder_date
    ,NOW() as tmodifydate 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 
    '2015-05-25' as dshipment_date
    ,20 as icmd_days
    ,'2015-05-28' as darrival_date
    ,0 as edelete
    ,'Active' as csubscriptionstatus
    ,20150004 as bisubscriptionID
    ,null as dadmin_reminder_date
    ,NOW() as tmodifydate 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 
    '2015-04-27' as dshipment_date
    ,20 as icmd_days
    ,'2015-04-30' as darrival_date
    ,0 as edelete
    ,'Shipped' as csubscriptionstatus
    ,20150005 as bisubscriptionID
    ,null as dadmin_reminder_date
    ,NOW() as tmodifydate 
;

SELECT * FROM `tbl_subscription`;

SELECT dshipment_date,icmd_days,DATE_ADD(dshipment_date, INTERVAL icmd_days DAY) FROM `tbl_subscription`;


UPDATE `tbl_subscription`
SET dprevious_shipment_date = dshipment_date
    ,csubscriptionstatus = 'Active'
    ,dshipment_date=DATE_ADD(dshipment_date, INTERVAL icmd_days DAY)
    ,tmodifydate = NOW()
WHERE darrival_date <= NOW()
AND edelete='0' 
AND csubscriptionstatus='Shipped' 
/*AND bisubscriptionID= $bisubscriptionID -- this is not needed since we are not doing the loop anymore -- */
;

SELECT * FROM `tbl_subscription`;
```

But the basic code you will need will be this:

```
USE stackoverflow;
UPDATE `tbl_subscription`
SET dprevious_shipment_date = dshipment_date
    ,csubscriptionstatus = 'Active'
    ,dshipment_date=DATE_ADD(dshipment_date, INTERVAL icmd_days DAY)
    ,tmodifydate = NOW()
WHERE darrival_date <= NOW()
AND edelete='0' 
AND csubscriptionstatus='Shipped' 
/*AND bisubscriptionID= $bisubscriptionID -- this is not needed since we are not doing the loop anymore -- */
```

And this code will remove the need for your loop to set the value of the csubscriptionstatus.

I added a field dprevious_shipment_date to your table as a date so that you can track when the previous month shipment went out in case you need it for recovery purposes you can remove that from the update statement as well if needed.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, I'll check tonight after work.

Comment: Awesome just let me know if this does not work. Please do mark this as answered if it does :-) I am trying to get my score up so that I can comment as woot suggested earlier when I have questions :-)

Comment: DateAdd() is an undefined function. I should mention that this is a .php file

Comment: Is this for mysql or SQL Server?

Comment: OK I got you setup with an edit to my original answer. You can use the code above to test on your MySQL server if you would like or just try out the update statement. I am not sure but I renamed the vsubscriptionstatus to csubscriptionstatus but I am not sure that is what you need so feel free to rename it back if you like.

Comment: also my schema is stackoverflow so you may have to change that if you are testing this out in MySQL

Comment: I do have another question. I have a page that contains a link to update their order. I want the link disabled if the "dshipment_date" is today or tomorrow. I believe I have to do this in jquery and have written the code to disable the link my problem is the if statement. I cant seem to figure out how to get the dshippment_date for a specific order into the jquery. I can post the code later if that would help?

Comment: Please do and make sure you post it as a new question :-)

Thanks for marking this as an answer :-)

Also post a link in the comments here so I can find your new question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30657285/disable-link-based-on-mysql-value-select-dshipment-date-from-tbl-member-where-me

Comment: Also we really are willing to pay someone to take a look at the .php our website runs to finalize the checkout process.

Comment: I appreciate the offer but I am not a PHP expert, at least not yet :-) 

https://www.linkedin.com/in/ryanhocking